# How to run a VB6 app from a scheduled task without users being able to run it

Tags: vb6, scheduled-tasks

We have a legacy VB6 application that automatically emails reports. It runs from a scheduled task on a server. Occasionally a user will run the exe - it's in a folder that we can't lock them out of, and it has to remain in that folder for reasons too complicated to go into here. Is there a way to prevent users from running the exe while still letting it run from the scheduled task? I can modify the source code for the exe, so that's an option if someone can help me figure out how.

Comment: Not really programming-related. More relevant for [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com)?

Comment: Just assign the program permissions that don't allow random users to execute it.

Comment: Bob77, that's what I want to do, but I don't know how. Can you point me to information on assigning those permissions, and what I'd have to set them to so that a scheduled task would run but random users can't run the exe by double-clicking it (or by any other means)?

Comment: C-Pound Guru, I thought this might be solved by adding something to the source code to restrict who can run it, that's why I asked the question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to call your existing app AppChild and a new VB6 (or other program language) program AppParent.

Modify AppChild to test for a command line parameter at either Sub Main() or at the first form loaded in the Form_Load() event. If the command line parameter isn't there, AppChild terminates.

AppParent would be in a location not accessible to the other users. The Scheduled task runs AppParent which runs AppChild and passes the required command line parameter. This could be secured somewhat by passing a calculated hash and decoding it in AppChild if needed.

Or, if the users don't have access to the Scheduled Tasks, you could just run AppChild , passing the required parameter from the Scheduled Task. If the users do have access to the Scheduled Task this won't work because they could then see the passed parameter and create a shortcut which passes the required parameter.

You didn't state which OS the server is running but you may have problems using network resources if you try to run the Scheduled Task without a logged in user. Task Manager got a major update to handle security issues to prevent hackers from running tasks without a logged in user. Essentailly, network resources, .e.g. eMail, are not available unless a user is logged in.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722152(v=ws.11).aspx

The only way I found around that problem is to run a machine with a user with the correct permissions logged in all the time.

Comment: thx1138v2 - it's running Windows Server 2003, and we can run scheduled tasks without a logged in user. I'm going to try passing a command line parameter from the scheduled task, I think this is going to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you cannot lock the user out? 
You could restrict access to the folder so that the user cannot access it and set up the scheduled task to use an account with access to the folder.

Comment: Although that would be ideal, I've been told we can't restrict access to this folder. I was wondering if there was a way to give the Task Scheduler a user name and password and code the VB6 application to only run for that account.

Comment: You could maybe do something with the Environment.UserName property, that one should tell you who it is that's runing the environemt (not shure if it checks who is logged in or which credentials are used for the process). I would do a test with a console application that only logs that data to file. When you set up the scheduled task there is an option to run even if user is not loged on where you set the user credentialsto use. Set it to run ecery 5 min and then trigger it manually a few times as well. That should give you enough input to see if you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Although the users can't be locked out of the folder (perhaps the reports end up in there?), in Windows you can set the permissions on a per file basis.  Make a new user that has the full rights (the same as your users).  Schedule the VB6 app to run with that user.   Remove the rights for the regular users to see the app.  You do this by changing the permissions on just the VB6 app.

Comment: VB6 is not VBA.